# Accessing NAS and media storage over wifi repeater/extender

Tags: wireless-networking, nas, storage, wireless-extender

I'm considering of buying some wifi range extender or repeater in order to extend range of my wifi.
But I have a concern about accessing media storage and file server from the router. I've external HDD attached to main router and not sure whether in will still be available through repeater/extender as some of them create a new subnet.
Regarding device I'm looking to buy Netgear N300.
Can you please advice whether media files from external HDD connected to main router will still be available on extended or repeated network?

Comment: A repeater by definition does not create a new subnet.

Comment: make sure you are buying a bridge/extender not a router. routers define networks, but bridges, switches, repeaters, and APs sit within an IP network.

Comment: @FrankThomas problem is that I don't know whether it's repeater or not, according to description on Amazon it should be, but people in reviews write about network with separate name.

Comment: then why are you looking at that particular device if you can't tell from the marketing what it is?

Comment: @FrankThomas almost all items on Amazon have word "repeater" listed, but many of them have quite inaccurate descriptions. I might consider different device.

Comment: try speciing out the item on a more tech-focused site like newegg or whatever, and then go to amazon with the model number of the item. Amazon isn't specific enough for tech specs sometimes.